# Debug Typescript files in Docker container with VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I've been bashing my head over this over a couple hours now and can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere -

I've a simple Node API setup in a Docker container written in Typescript and I'm trying to use VSCode to attach to it to debug. I'm able to connect to it (and the Debug console shows it) but as soon as I try to set a breakpoint I get back `Breakpoints set but not yet bound`.

Here's my launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Docker",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port":9229,
      "restart": true,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "remoteRoot": "/api",
      "protocol" : "inspector",
      "trace": "verbose"
    }
  ]
}
```

Terminal output with debugger

```
web_1       | Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/44aca479-580c-4ecb-a104-cf80f9041538                                              │
web_1       | For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector                                                                       
web_1       | Debugger attached.
```

The node app gets started up with `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229`. I tried to run some Mocha tests but all the breakpoints I set earlier get completely ignored. Can anyone help me and take a look? Here's my current [repo](https://github.com/andrewgu12/KSA-KExpo/tree/redo-api) but I'll work on setting up a simple TS app in Docker to try and narrow down the possibilities.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, or if I have read your question properly...but I just simply map my (node) container volume to my (local) drive that contains my vscode?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow @Intellidroid

Comment: In my docker compose file I will set the volume to map to a local folder where my code is ..... so" Volumes:  ./vscode-nodeserver-files: /directory-in-container"

Comment: how do you run your mocha tests? I'd guess the package script that runs them is different to that which starts your api/application and therefore mocha scripts aren't being inspected.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this makes more sense.
If you have a look at the Dockerfile in the server dir and then look what I do on the compose file

[node container](https://github.com/alphagov/sd-servicedesk-tools)

Comment: Oh! Yeah, I have that in my docker-compose: this? https://github.com/andrewgu12/KSA-KExpo/blob/acc5dba0c723569e35263672a003a53cfe3cd343/docker-compose.yml#L16